# Why hibernate create 50000000000000001 in first record?

Tags: java, hibernate, sybase

I use Hibernate with Sybase to create a new record :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID")
```

This is my query to create a field in the DB :

```
ID bigint  IDENTITY NOT NULL
```

After creating the first record the ID is 50000000000000001. What is wrong? I want the first value to be 1.

Comment: you should change your strategy to GenerationType.Auto

Comment: i changed GenerationType.Auto and get 50000000000000002. after i delete table and re-add result is 1.

Comment: so is it working??

Comment: I dont think it is a hibernate problem

Comment: Yes this is problem of Sybase . http://www.xaazg.com/62594612.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably occurred after an abnormal shutdown of Sybase. There is a good explanation [here](http://www.xaazg.com/62594612.html). 
The best way to "recover" it is running the `sp_chgattribute` [command](http://infocenter-archive.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc36271_36272_36273_36274_1250/html/refman/X42067.htm), like this:

```
sp_chgattribute "table_name", "identity_gap", set_number
```